# Что такое динамический массив

Tags: терминология

Часто стал видеть в интернете и здесь, на РУСО, как авторы, говоря о динамических массивах, понимают под этим словом массив, который создан во время работы программы, то есть на Си вот такой массив:

```
int * array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));
```

Но когда я изучал программирование, нас учили что динамический массив это что-то более сложное. Это массив размер котрого можно менять в процессе работы программы.

Термин поменял свое содержание, расширился или люди ошибаются?

Comment: Вы написали - размер которого можно менять в процессе работы программы. Я в ответе привел возможность realloc, другой вариант тривиален - Вы вводите число array_size и создаете массив такого размера. Вполне себе изменение (0 -> array_size) во время работы программы.

Answer (score 3):

Динамическим называется массив, размер которого, при необходимости, может меняться во время исполнения программы. Это верное определение.

```
int * array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));
```

Это и есть пример динамического массива. Ты можешь ниже в программе выделить ему новую память, расширить или сузить его.

Отличие статических от динамических массивов в том, что размер первого определяется на момент компиляции, а размер второго, может меняться в программе

Answer (score 3):

> Динамическим называется массив, размер которого, при необходимости, может меняться во время исполнения программы. Для изменения размера динамического массива язык программирования, поддерживающий такие массивы, должен предоставлять встроенную функцию или оператор. Динамические массивы дают возможность более гибкой работы с данными, так как позволяют не прогнозировать хранимые объёмы данных, а регулировать размер массива в соответствии с реально необходимыми объёмами. В отличие от динамических массивов существуют статические массивы и массивы переменной длины. Размер статического массива определяется на момент компиляции программы. Размер массива переменной длины определяется во время выполнения программы. Отличием динамического массива от массива переменной длины является автоматическое изменение размеров, что не трудно реализуется в случаях его отсутствия, поэтому часто не различают массивы переменной длины с динамическими массивами

Материал взят из [статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) с Википедии.

Массив, который создается таким образом - динамический:

```
int * array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int))
```

И Вы можете поменять его размер на этапе выполнения, например, через `realloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <malloc.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main()  
{  
    long *buffer, *oldbuffer;  
    size_t size;  

   if((buffer = (long*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(long ))) == NULL)  
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  

   size = _msize(buffer);  
   printf_s("Size of block after malloc of 1000 longs: %u\n", size);

   oldbuffer = buffer;  
   if((buffer = realloc(buffer, size + (1000 * sizeof(long))))  ==  NULL)  
   {  
      free(oldbuffer); 
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
   }  

   size = _msize( buffer );  
   printf_s("Size of block after realloc of 1000 more longs: %u\n",   
        size);  

   free(buffer);  
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
}
```

Пример взят с [сайта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xbebcx7d.aspx) справки MSDN.

Альтернатива - это *статический массив*, его размер не меняется во время исполнения программы и определяется в момент компиляции программы. Можно сказать, что динамический массив - это массив, размер которого задается как константой, так и переменной, поэтому употребление термина массив *переменной длины* будет уместным.

Comment: откуда цитата-то?

Comment: @Grundy википедия

Comment: Добавь ссылку на исходную статью в ответ

Comment: *Отличием динамического массива от массива переменной длины является автоматическое изменение размеров* Сомнительная фраза. В примере кода изменение размера выполняется явно функцией `realloc()` - т.е. в примере мы видим массив переменной длины. Если исходить из цитаты, то динамический массив - это массив, размер которого будет автоматически, без пользовательского кода, увеличен при попытке обратиться (вероятно, при присвоении значения - ибо сгенерить фэйк при чтении можно и так) к его элементу за пределами текущего размера этого массива, без генерации out of bounds error.

Comment: @Akina думаю, это можно трактовать как: вот программа начала работать, мы ввели значение, массив создался размером, равным этому значению, т.е. определился автоматически во время работы.

Comment: @Jenssen Это хорошо укладывается в определение массива переменной длины - ведь мы задаём новые размеры массиву явно, кодом. Собственно я к тому, что массивов, описанных в Вики как динамические, в общем-то и не бывает... описанное там поведение характерно скорее для коллекций (к тому же разреженных - которых тоже не бывает).